# Add action to actionbar

Tags: c#, android

Im new at android development and im looking to make an actionbar and add an action to it. But it seems like i cant "render" the actionbar

1- **MainMenu.xml**

```
   <menu  android:id="@+id/toolbar"   
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
 tools:context=".MainActivity">
 <item android:id="@+id/actionNew" android:icon="@drawable/ic_new" android:title="New"         android:showAsAction="always" />
   </menu>
```

2- **Main.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <ListView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="513.0dp"
        android:id="@+id/parksListView"
        android:layout_marginTop="90" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this guide, 
The app bar, also known as the action bar...
https://developer.android.com/training/appbar

Or another tutorial,
https://www.journaldev.com/9357/android-actionbar-example-tutorial

Comment: Yeah thank you but the problem is that this is correct but doesnt show what its supposed to show!